# C# Generics "Cannot convert System.ValueType to T" (Unity Prefs)

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I have this function which get's the following error in the compiler: *cannot convert System.ValueType to T* and the typeof(string) block gives the error: *cannot convert type 'string' to 'T'*

```
public static T ReadKey<T>(GamePrefs.Key k, T defaultValue)
    {
        T obj = defaultValue;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
            obj = (T)(ValueType)(bool)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), !(bool)(object)defaultValue ? 0 : 1) == 1 ? true : false);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            obj = (T)(ValueType)PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), (int)(object)defaultValue);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
            obj = (T)(ValueType)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(k.ToString(), (float)(object)defaultValue);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            obj = (T)PlayerPrefs.GetString(k.ToString(), (string)(object)defaultValue);
        else
            Debug.LogError((object)string.Format("Key {0} couldn't be read because type {1} not supported.", (object)k, (object)typeof(T)));
        return obj;
    }
```

What's the problem in here?

Comment: `Debug.LogError((object)string.Format("Key {0} couldn't be read because type {1} not supported.", (object)k, (object)typeof(T)));` Format calls the ToString method. Might be worth a look at the `GetType()` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: I would point to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/446515) by Eric Lippert in a similar question.

Comment: The line under the first `if` has all kinds of wtf in it and can be replaced by `obj = (bool)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), defaultValue ? 1 : 0) == 1);` but I have no idea whether that will solve your problem.

Comment: Says: *Can't implicitly convert type 'T' to 'bool'* (the parameter defaultValue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very overcomplicated - there is no need for a generic parameter. The type is known at compile-time. Create four overloaded methods:

```
public static bool ReadKey(GamePrefs.Key k, bool defaultValue)
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), defaultValue ? 1 : 0) == 1;
}

public static int ReadKey(GamePrefs.Key k, int defaultValue)
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), defaultValue);
}

public static float ReadKey(GamePrefs.Key k, float defaultValue)
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(k.ToString(), defaultValue);
}

public static string ReadKey(GamePrefs.Key k, string defaultValue)
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetString(k.ToString(), defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: It works. And yeah it's complicated, well I thought that it would be easier to use generics in my situation, guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick, no errors:

```
public static T ReadKey<T>(GamePrefs.Key k, T defaultValue)
    {
        T obj = defaultValue;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
            obj = (T)Convert.ChangeType((bool)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), !(bool)(object)defaultValue ? 0 : 1) == 1 ? true : false), typeof(T));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            obj = (T)Convert.ChangeType((PlayerPrefs.GetInt(k.ToString(), (int)(object)defaultValue)), typeof(T));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
            obj = (T)Convert.ChangeType((PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(k.ToString(), (float)(object)defaultValue)), typeof(T));
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            obj = (T)Convert.ChangeType((PlayerPrefs.GetString(k.ToString(), (string)(object)defaultValue)), typeof(T));
        else
            Debug.LogError((object)string.Format("Key {0} couldn't be read because type {1} not supported.", (object)k, (object)typeof(T)));
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: You cast too much. You're still going from `T` to `object` back to essentially `T`. You should be able to remove the casting of `object`. Also really confused on your `GetXType` calls where I would think it would return you the type it says, but then you pass it into `Convert.ChangeType`.