# FieldWrapper<T> pattern

Tags: c#

I had a class similar to this, which is basically meant to wrap a base type (int, long, bool, string, ...) and keep track of whether it has been modified or not.

```
public class FieldWrapper<T>
{
    public bool HasBeenModified = false;

    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((_value == null && value != null) || (_value != null && !_value.Equals(value)))
            {
                this.HasBeenModified = true;
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

and I used it like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public readonly FieldWrapper<int> a = new FieldWrapper<int>();
    public readonly FieldWrapper<int> b = new FieldWrapper<int>();

    public void DoThings()
    {
        a.Value = 2+1;
        b.Value = a.Value;
    }
}
```

but I really disliked this `.value` spreading everywhere, so I thought to create some implicit casts and added these lines:

```
public static implicit operator T(FieldWrapper<T> value)
{
    return value.Value;
}

public static implicit operator FieldWrapper<T>(T value)
{
    return new FieldWrapper<T>() { Value = value, HasBeenModified = true };
}
```

and it's almost all perfect and fine, but a thing.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public FieldWrapper<int> a = new FieldWrapper<int>();
    public FieldWrapper<int> b = new FieldWrapper<int>();

    public void DoThings()
    {
        a = 2+1;
        b = a;
    }
}
```

Now `a = 2+1` is effectively an assignment to a new object and the variable cannot be readonly anymore. `b = a` now works differently from the previous version: it copies `a` reference into `b` and so its `HasBeenModified` field.

Is this `FieldWrapper<T>` pattern fixable in some way I'm missing?

Edit:

Context and what I want to achieve.

I do have a series of classes whose structure (fields) is reflected into the database. For example, if there is a

```
class DbClass1
{
    [DbFieldAttribute]
    public FieldWrapper<int> exampleField;
}
```

then there is also a table on the database called 'DbClass1' which has 'exampleField' as integer column.
This class is read and saved to database using auto-generated queries.
I wanted to avoid unnecessary UPDATE queries when the object did not change since the last load.

*And possibly, only update the fields that really changed (I'm rethinking about this part, since for collection of items a bulk-update is probably more performing than single punctual updates, and for single updates the gain is probably not worth the effort of adding complexity to the code).*

So, I basically just need a boolean for the class (not for each single field) to signal if this object/record has to be updated or it is not necessary.

my first guess would be
class DbClass1
{
private bool hasBeenModified = false;

```
    int _exampleField;
    [DbFieldAttribute]
    public int exampleField
    {
        get
        {
            return exampleField;
        }
        set
        {
            if() //check if old value is different from new value
            {
                hasBeenModified = true;
                _exampleField= value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if there is a more compact way to do that it would be perfect

Comment: Logically speaking, I don't think `_value == null` should always mean `this.HasBeenModified = true;`.  Using `!_value.Equals(value)` should be sufficient.  Also, in your last example, `b` is not defined.

Comment: I cannot call `_value.Equals` if `_value` is null (if T is not a primitive type - e.g. strings)
I should check if the new value is also equals to null, in that case it indeed didn't change, but null assignment is assumed to never happen in my application.
fixing the `b` definition :)

Comment: I'm sure there's a solution to your problem, but have you considered, "Any time you find yourself switching on a type in a generic you are almost certainly doing something wrong. Generics should be generic; they should operate identically completely independent of the type." Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/1477388 I think that principle applies here.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. That said, I think that your attempt to declare the variable as `readonly` is misguided to start with, and just highlights a failure in the original design concept. That is, why would a field that ostensibly can be modified be declared as `readonly`? I mean, sure...it syntactically works, but mutable `readonly` fields can be confusing, and this seems especially so when the whole point of the field is to track the mutation. There are lots of alternatives to your current design; without more context and constraints, which one is best can't be known.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm totally open to different solutions for the problem.
I'll edit the question to add a context

Comment: I read this question as: "Is there some way I can override the implicit "conversion to `FieldWrapper`" operator in a way that I don't lose the `HasBeenModified` functionality of the class". Is that correct? Or it has to do with `readonly` fields?

Comment: @RufusL the original question was something more like "when i assign `FieldWrapper A` to `Fieldwrapper B`, i get `B` to have the `HasBeenModified` value of `A`, but should be forced to `true`. we can ignore the readonly part.

Comment: @RufusL actually, it does not only take its `HasBeenModified` value, but takes its whole reference, which is even worst. a FieldWrapper<T> to FieldWrapper<T> custom cast would have been what i needed, but this sounds so wierd that i cleary understand that i'm not on the right track

Comment: I haven't tried the code, but it looks like `b = a` will end up with `b.Value == a` rather than `b.Value == a.Value`. Is that the case?

Comment: @RufusL unfortunately not, when i do `b = a` then i end up with `b == a`, a and b will share reference, and a modify on one of the two will be reflected on the other. I would need a `public static implicit operator DbField<T>(DbField<T> value)` to create a new object, but that is reasonably not allowed