# How to cast a variable of specific type to generic T in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, casting, type-conversion, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Depending on the actual type of T, I want to return a specific value; here a simplified example (a record wrapper around some object):

```
function TMyRec.TryGet<T>(const Default: T): T;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyObject) then
    Result:= FMyObject {E2010 Incompatible types}
  else Result:= FMyObject.TryGet<T>(Default);
end;
```

It's clear that I cannot assign anything other than `T` to `Result`, and `as T` or `T()` don't work, when `T` is not restricted to `class`...

It's also not possible to do an overload which differs only in the generic restriction:

```
function TryGet<T: TMyObject>(const Default: T): T; overload;
{...}
Result:= FMyObject as T; {here it would work}
```

---

To help understand the discussion in the comments below, here is the example from before my edit:

```
function TMyRec.TryGet<T>(const Default: T): T;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyObject) then Result:= FMyObject
  //else ...
  else Result:= Default;
end;
```

Comment: If T is marked as class `TryGet<T: class>` then you can do `MyObject as T` in Delphi XE and newer. You can then also do `T(MyObject)` in Delphi 2010 and newer.

Comment: That's true - forgot to mention that I need this not only for objects... Will edit.

Comment: The simplest way is the one you used in the answer, IMHO.

Comment: The answer is, it depends. There are lots of different possible conversions for different combinations of types. You are going to need to decide what the spec is.

Comment: I'll just [refer to Eric Lippert here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/327083), but you might consider that a generic solution in this case is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: @J..., I like and agree to Eric Lippert, and it is good to mention it here. Everyone who has the same question should first think twice. Sometimes, however, generics are only used to improve comfort for the lazy user of the class and I can accept to leave the optimal methodology behind in this case. Imagine you had to write something like TValue without such compromises :) - feel free to write a more comprehensive answer, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: @maf-soft I can't write you an answer because I have no idea what problem you are actually trying to solve.  All I can say is that, given the way you are trying to solve it, generics are probably not the correct solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the spec is in the example code: type is T without restriction, and the value to be assigned is an object. But of course it would be insteresting to learn what other cases would need special attention.

Comment: @J... - I think you are trying to read between the lines too much. Since I already posted an answer myself, you can see what an acceptable answer would look like for me. The question is just, how can I make `Result:= FMyObject` work? I didn't write down all the background information because my question was just this. I can't change the concept of my 2000+ lines class structure. And if you didn't notice: I already have my solution - I wrote it down to help others after I couldn't find an existing solution here at stackoverflow.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me. If you know what the types are why are you using a generic. I'm confused, I think you are too.

Comment: I agree with @David: if you must use an if-else ladder or similar (e.g. case statements) to return the value, you are not using generics. Then you can just as well use overloaded methods instead.

Comment: Yes, a complete and good answer should include all these concerns and suggestions **in addition** to the direct answer to the question. Yes, developers with the same question should rethink their concept and **maybe** solve it in a different way. But that was not the question and I believe such concerns should not lead to the question or correct answers beeing downvoted.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, let's imagine for a second I have reasons you all could accept if you knew them. How should I have asked this simple question in a general way, without explaining the whole background? The code is just an example to better understand the question in the title. I don't want to explain my special case in full length because I already solved it myself and the intention to post here was to help others looking for the same question. When I cannot find my question here, I post it, and when I find the answer myself, I post it, too. I think that's what everyone should do.

Comment: Surprise, I edited the example to be much more like what I really do. Seems my simplification wasn't a simplification, it's now even shorter :) @RudyVelthuis

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Some concrete examples would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is using `System.Rtti.TValue` (exception if wrong type):

```
Result:= TValue.From(FMyObject).AsType<T>
```

or much shorter ;-) with automatic type (returns false if wrong type; you could ignore that here because you already checked TypeInfo):

```
TValue.From(FMyObject).TryAsType(Result)
```

Suggestion: rethink your concept; there are [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292236/how-to-cast-a-variable-of-specific-type-to-generic-t-in-delphi?noredirect=1#comment87604481_50292236) that generics might not be a good solution, but we cannot tell without knowing more about the background.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers.

Comment: I think this solution is quite nice and I will use it, but what if I don't like to use `TValue` - is there another smart way? Looking forward to additional answers...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, @J, I just wanted to encourage others to post additional answers if there are other or better interesting solutions I'm not aware of. It wasn't a real question. The real question is in the question and a good answer is in the answer, to help people with the same problem. What you do is nitpicking. Not every question mark is a serious crime. Anyway, I removed it...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the best method (performance-wise at least) to achieve what you want.

```
type 
  PMyObject = ^TMyObject;

function TMyRec.TryGet<T>(const Default: T): T;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyObject) then 
    PMyObject(@Result)^ := FMyObject
  else if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then 
    PInteger(@Result)^ := 1
  //else ...
  else
    Result := Default;
end;
```

Comment: Great, so TValue is not the only way, good to know an alternative. Why do you think this is the best method? To me it looks like a hack. However, I don't understand why someone already downvoted this, it adds value and is helpful. Thanks. Downvoters should always post their reason.

Comment: @maf It's been discussed many times on meta, voting is anonymous. You don't need to justify how you vote. Up or down. This is a really poor answer. With two up votes. I'd love to know how it could have been upvoted.

Comment: @David: what is so poor about it? It is more or less what I thought about posting too, when I was away from my Delphi setup: do not cast the result value to T, cast Result to the type (indirectly). This is not how you should generally use generics, but sometimes a situation like this can happen. And it is IMO preferrable to RTTI. And yes, of course it is a hack. Generally, one should not have to cast like that. Usually, you either don't use generics or you don't cast.

Comment: Of course, sometimes you don't want Rtti in the uses clause or you don't like the (small) overhead. So it's good to know I could do it this way. But to me, Rtti looks less hackish and more readable, so I decided to prefer it this time.

Comment: What if the type is derived from TMyObject? Or is a different integral type? This is a poor method, incorrectly implemented.

Comment: @maf-soft I clarified what I meant.  As far as performance goes, it will be a LOT better than using TValue.  Even if you end up with lots of if/else, the compiler will usually optimise them out and leave only the assignation.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Delphi XE5.

Change yoru sample to this:

```
function TryGet<T: class>(const Default: T): T; overload;
{...}
Result:= FMyObject as T; {here it will work}
```

The change is `TMyObject` to `class`. When you are not "class" it, you will get the compiler error E2089.

Comment: But the requirement is that it has to work for any type. This was also discussed in the comments already.

Comment: @maf-soft you are right. Everybody looks for answers. Me, too. I do not read comments. I also missed the point of *any* type, because first sentence was "(a record wrapper around some object)". Note for me: read more carefully.

Comment: For me it's ok when you just delete this answer :)