# How to check a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have class `Repository` which takes data from `DataSource` class.

Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DataSource Context;

    public Repository(DataSource context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

DataSource:

```
public class DataSource
{
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        switch (typeof(TEntity))
        {
            case :

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have to check type of `TEntity` and depends on it, choose method which returns a `List<Plane>` or `List<Flight>` and so on. How can I do it, or there is other way?

Comment: Please don't use the Repository Anti-Pattern ( https://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/05/05/what-is-that-all-about-the-repository-anti-pattern/ ) - and if you're using Entity Framework then the `DbContext` **is** your repository.

Comment: Agreed, making a repository layer on top of the unit-of-work layer already provided to you by EF is indeed an anti-pattern, and is undesirable.

Comment: I now, but it is my task, i dont have any db i have just use some class with written data.

Comment: I'm going to throw in a solid piece of wisdom from [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/327083) : ***"Any time you find yourself switching on a type in a generic you are almost certainly doing something wrong."***

Comment: You have a generic.  Why return a `List<Plane>` when you can return a `List<TEntity>`?  Why is the switch needed, at all?

Comment: Because of TEntity type i return different data, if TEntity is Plane i will return List<Plane> and so on

Comment: Take a look at a Pattern Matching switch statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements

Comment: I concur with what has already been said. The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: @Pavlo I think you misunderstand how generics work.  `TEntity` *is* `Plane`.

Comment: So if you want brittle (error prone to change) code and also abstract away many of the benefits and more complex query options then keep going but I strongly recommend against it (as does everyone who already commented likewise).

Comment: It is a task, i have to do it in this way

Comment: It's a task.  Unless this is a school assignment, you have a responsibility not to follow orders blindly, but to inform your superiors when a task does not appear reasonable, as is the case here.  You've got a half dozen programmers telling you "this is bad" and "don't do this", and stating specifically *why* it's bad.

Comment: Let say you are not correcting anti pattern code, how are you going to return List<Plane>?

Comment: @J... is correct; this is a really bad idea. Don't do it.  If your method has four cases in the switch then **simply write four methods**, one for each type.  Because **that's what you're doing; you're just putting the body of each method into a case section**.  Just make the methods!

Answer (score 2):

Don't switch.  If you need different behaviour for different types then write strongly typed methods for those types.  [Generics should be generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/327083).  If the behaviour you are implementing isn't generic then don't use generics.

```
public IEnumerable<Plane> Set<Plane>()
{
    // ...
}

public IEnumerable<Flight> Set<Flight>()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Please try this before start switch case

```
var objectName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
```

Then check that objectName as case.