# How to convert ObservableCollection<SomeType> back to ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, return-type, generic-collections

I am struggling with converion back to generic collection type in generic method with return type.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/11027921) is clearly written to avoid

> switching on a type in a generic

But in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171476/11027921) is explained how to do it.

I admit, that I used generics to avoid writing three times the same code for three different return types. Right now the compiler is telling me, that

> not all code paths return a value

Example of caller methods caller:

```
public ObservableCollection<LoadedJockey> Jockeys { get; private set; }

Jockeys = await _updateDataService.UpdateDataAsync(Jockeys, DataUpdateModules.JPlFrom, DataUpdateModules.JPlTo, "updateJockeysPl");
```

My generic method looks like this:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> UpdateDataAsync<T>(ObservableCollection<T> genericCollection, int idFrom, int idTo, string jobType) where T : IConvertible
        {
            //variables reset here
            _loopCounterProgressBar = 0;
            _idFromProgressBar = idFrom;
            _idToProgressBar = idTo;

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedHorse))
            {
                //do something here
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedJockey))
            {
                //do something here
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedHistoricalRace))
            {
                //do something here
            }

            //initial
            SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(_degreeOfParallelism);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token;
            OnProgressBarTick();

            //run loop
            for (int i = idFrom; i < idTo; i++)
            {
                int id = i;

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;

                        await throttler.WaitAsync(TokenSource.Token);

                        if (jobType.Contains("Horses"))
                        {
                            await //call service method
                        }
                        else if (jobType.Contains("Jockeys"))
                        {
                            await //call service method
                        }
                        else if (jobType.Contains("Historic"))
                        {
                            await //call service method
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _loopCounterProgressBar++;

                        EventHandler<UpdateBarEventArgs> progressBarTick = _updateProgressEventHandler;

                        OnProgressBarTick();

                        throttler.Release();
                    }
                }));
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                //save results in file when finish

                }
            }
            //here I wanted to return some result depending on T
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedHorse))
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<T>)Convert.ChangeType(Horses, typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedJockey))
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<T>)Convert.ChangeType(Jockeys, typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(LoadedHistoricalRace))
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<T>)Convert.ChangeType(Races, typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I expect to receive 3 different types of **T**. And I think that I covered all of them. My solution is based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171476/11027921). I am guessing, that I may `Convert` wrongly my type to `T`, but I do not how I am supposed to do it.

Comment: You have a chain of ifs and else-ifs, but the compiler doesn't know that it will fall into one of those (in fact, it's completely valid if you pass any other T). Just add a final `else { throw new ArgumentException() }` or something

Comment: Does the caller of update data know about the type? Maybe provide Dependency injection of the "Do work here" by a `Func<>` or `Action<>` which can be leveraged on the caller to determine the right course of action. ???

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `else { throw new ArgumentException(); }` at the end of the chain did not work :(

Comment: @ΩmegaMan yes, I updated the question with **Example of caller of the method**. I started considering to use event aggregator pattern if I will not find any solution to return back generic.

Comment: @bakunet By "did not work", do you mean that you get the same error if you add that `else{}` block, or a different error? How about if you `return null;`? And neither of those actually needs to go in an `else` block. You could just put them at the end of the method, after the last `else if` block.

Comment: Strategy pattern seems applicable here. That way `T` aligns up with the `T` in `ObservableCollection<T>`, and casting is not required.

Comment: @JLRishe Sorry I didnt specify, now I have **The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'UpdateService.UpdateDataAsync<T>(ObservableCollection<T>, int, int, string)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IUpdateService.UpdateDataAsync<T>(ObservableCollection<T>, int, int, string)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.**

Comment: There's a design problem with your generic method. The typechecking and the need to ask this question. i would advise writing several different non generic methods and get them working. Then start refactoring towards sharing code, without any runtime typechecking. Don't continue down this path, it's not worth it.

Comment: Your code is not well designed, you always should avoid type cheking. Based on your code, I think you should check the [strategy design pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern). I suggest you to refactor your code using this pattern to avoid type checking, this will also remove the cast problem.

Comment: Ok, I will try to re-design it and I will let you know guys.

Comment: Ok, my very very dumb mistake. Previously, after I started playing with generics in the method andadded to the signature `where T : IConvertible`, I forgot to update its signature in my intercace. So now it works with `else { throw new ArgumentException(); }`. Anyway, thanks to you guys I started reoganizing it, so if someone wants to take some credits for it, feel free to answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Camilo Terevinto** adviced, I added at the end of `if else` chain `else { throw new ArgumentException() }` and compiler was pleased.