# Why can't I cast an item to a generic type — where the generic type is an interface, and after checking that the item implements said interface?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

## Description

I'm trying to write effects (à la buffs/debuffs) for my game. Here's what I want to build:

The class `EffectsManager` houses all active effects. A class like `HealthController` queries it for health-related effects, i.e. effects that implement the `IHealthEffect` interface, and gets back a List containing only such effects.

## Attempted Solution

Inside `EffectsManager`:

```
public List<T> GetEffects<T>() {
    List<T> effects = new List<T>();

    foreach (ActiveEffect activeEffect in activeEffects) {
        // ActiveEffect is just a wrapper for Effect that houses duration, time elapsed, etc.
        // I only need to return the Effect itself, which houses the logic.
        Effect effect = activeEffect.GetEffect();
        if (effect is T) {
            effects.Add((T)effect);
        }
    }

    return effects;
}
```

And then, the caller script would write:

```
List<IHealthEffect> healthEffects = effectsManager.GetEffects<IHealthEffect>();
```

## Problem

> Cannot convert type 'Effect' to 'T'

On `effects.Add((T)effect);`.

## Similar Questions

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'Int' to 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171412/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-t)

But in my case, I'm doing not an implicit but an explicit cast. Why won't the compiler let me proceed, and should I use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#overloads) — as suggested there — anyway?

## More Info

`Effect` is just an abstract class with only 1 member: `public int priority;`.

Since an effect may affect multiple attributes, such as health *and* mana, I decided to go with interfaces that demand that the implementer write a specific method, e.g.: `void Execute(HealthController healthController);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
   if (effect is T typed) {
        effects.Add(typed);
   }
```

As for why: you'd need an `object` cast in the middle: `(T)(object)effect`

Comment: Thank you! That was a lot quicker than expected. Could you explain how `typed` works or link to a resource that does? Googling 'C# typed' or 'C# T typed' doesn't seem to give me anything.

Comment: @verified_tinker the `typed` here is just the variable name that we're declaring; it would work the same with `is T foo` and `Add(foo)`. This is a recent C# addition that allows you to do a "type-test and store in a local variable" in a single step, because it is so common and avoids a second cast; specifically it is the "pattern matching" feature in C# 7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching

Answer (score 1):

> But in my case, I'm doing not an implicit but an explicit cast.

`Effect` and `T` are unrelated, so the compiler will attempt a conversion rather than a cast, and clearly no conversion has been defined between the types either, hence the error.

As suggested by Marc, you could make full use of pattern matching:

```
if (effect is T t) {
     effects.Add(t);
}
```

But if your code is exactly as posted, you can achieve this entirely through LINQ:

```
var healthEffects = activeEffects.Select(x => x.GetEffect()).OfType<IHealthEffect>();
```

Comment: Beyond turning the code into a one-liner, are there any advantages — e.g. performance — to using LINQ over the standard `foreach` implementation?

Comment: 1) It can be more memory efficient, as a list does not need to be allocated if you simply need to iterate over the items. Although the same could be achieved using `yield return` 2) It reduces unnecessary code in your code-base. Why create additional methods when the framework has equivalents? 3) It is more flexible: you could easily chain additional LINQ methods as necessary such as `Where` etc.