# In C# Casting between objects descending from one another in a generic function requires a null check

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I have two classes (entities, actually) which are descending from one another:

```
public class BankAccount : AccountBase
{ .. }
```

I also have a service method that is responsible for saving all these entities. Due to some legacy code, the actual adding/updating of the entity might be delegated to a different service depending on the entity type.

Here is the prototype of the method of the second service

```
    public interface IBankService
    {
        Task<BankAccount> AddBankAsync(BankAccount bankData, ISecurityContext securityContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
        ...
    }
```

And here is the method in the main service that should be able to save any AccountBase entity:

```
        public async Task<T> AddGeneralLedgerAsync<T>(T generalLedgerData, ISecurityContext securityContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T: AccountBase
        {
            if (generalLedgerData is BankAccount bankAccount)
            {
                // The following cast should always work since BankAccount descends from AccountBase
                if ((await bankService.AddBankAsync(bankAccount, securityContext, cancellationToken)) is T res)
                    return res;
                else 
                    throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot cast BankAccount to {generalLedgerData.GetType().Name}"); // this should never happen but it's necessary because the cast can return null if the types are incompatible
            }
            // Code for saving other entity types goes here
        }
```

The code above works but it doesn't feels right: since BankAccount descends from AccountBase, the cast between the two should always work and never return a null. The null check should therefore not be necessary.

Moreover, that should be checkable at compile time and the runtime check shouldn't be necessary.

**Is there a way to perform the same operation that doesn't require that null check?**

(Note that nullable reference types are enabled everywhere)

Comment: Which null check are you talking about?

Comment: Although `T` descends from `AccountBase`, `BankAccount` may not be descendant of `T` so the `is` type check may not return `true`. I'm not entirely sure about `null` here but your code does not seem to handle `null`.

Comment: Also why are you using generics if all you do is switch on the actual type? Can't you implement overloads for all the supported entity types instead?

Comment: Are you saying that since the outer `if` condition is true, there is no need to cast to `T`, because `T` has to be `BankAccount`? What if `T` is a subclass of `BankAccount`?

Comment: I think you need a `ServiceFactory` which you can do `GetService<T>()` and that will return to you a `IEntityService<T>` which in this case will be the `BankService`

Comment: This might just be a slight variation on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/8171412/4708150 and the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/4708150 suggests the same thing as @ZdeněkJelínek to just have overloads for each type that you are handling.