# C# casting error on generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a C# method where I am trying to use `generics` as:

```
unsafe private void PerformWindowLevel<T>(int lower, int upper, ref T[] pixels)
```

Somewhere along the function I have the following line:

```
float shift = ... // some value
float scale = ... // some value
float val = ((float)pixels[i] + shift) * scale;
```

Here I get the error `Cannot convert type 'T' to 'float'`.

The method is called as:

```
PerformWindowLevel<byte>(10, 100, ref pixels);
```

So I am converting a `byte` type to float which should be possible. `pixels` is a byte array declared as `public byte[] pixels;` and filled with valid values.

Comment: why do you want to use generic if you uses this method with <byte>?

Comment: How about `float val = (Convert.ToSingle((object)pixels[i] + shift)) * scale`? Applying generic constraint only restricts to certain type, if you want broader `T` types use conversion method (note that type parameter T can only converted to an object).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto This complains that I cannot use the (+) operator on object and float...

Comment: @DdarkSideE The method will also be used with other types like UInt16 etc. They will always be convertible to floats.

Comment: Seems I putting `Convert.ToSingle` method in wrong scope: `(Convert.ToSingle((object)pixels[i]) + shift)`. The `object` need to cast as `float` and perform addition with another `float`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto This worked! Want to write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cannot convert type 'T' to 'float'* indicates that the compiler simply doesn't know exactly what kind of data type that generic type parameter `T` currently has. Any attempt to cast `T` to other type except for `object` (as base class of all objects) will result `InvalidCastException`.

Hence, based from how generic type parameter works as explained above, the code can be written as this:

```
unsafe private void PerformWindowLevel<T>(int lower, int upper, ref T[] pixels)
{
    float shift = 3.0F; // some value
    float scale = 5.0F; // some value
    float val = (Convert.ToSingle((object)pixels[i]) + shift) * scale;
}
```

or include a check for `byte` data type before performing cast:

```
unsafe private void PerformWindowLevel<T>(int lower, int upper, ref T[] pixels)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
    {
        float shift = 3.0F; // some value
        float scale = 5.0F; // some value
        float val = (Convert.ToSingle((object)pixels[i]) + shift) * scale;
    }
}
```

Note that the generic itself should be completely independent of the type, so if type parameter `T` intended to just accept `byte` just use `ref byte[] pixels` instead.

NB: About the message *A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter*, it can be explained where `float` (`System.Single`) itself is just a `struct`, which is implicitly `sealed`. A struct or sealed class can't be used as generic type parameter constraint, but you can constrain that `T` *is a struct*. Currently valid constraints should be like this:

```
void GenericMethod<T>() where T: class // reference type constraint

void GenericMethod<T>() where T: struct {} // value type constraint

void GenericMethod<T>() where T: new() // public parameterless constructor constraint

void GenericMethod<T>() where T: IConvertible // interface constraint

void GenericMethod<T>() where T: BaseClass // base class constraint
```

More info: [Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Similar issues:

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'Int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170784/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-t-to-int)

[Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092393/value-of-type-t-cannot-be-converted-to)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `T` doesn´t know anything about what it might be in your calling code, it´s just a generic type-parameter, that could also be `string` or whatever which you (apparently) can´t cast to `float`. You´d need a generic constraint:

```
unsafe private void PerformWindowLevel<T>(int lower, int upper, ref T[] pixels) where T: float
```

This still doesn´t work as you can´t use a struct (which `float` is) as generic type-parameter. Only interfaces or classes are allowed.

However this would only allow `float` to be a valid generic parameter making the term generic quite - well - *ungeneric*. This is why generics are completely wrong in your case. When only one or two types are possible you should create a concrete method (or an overload) for that specific type. Generics on the other side state that every type (that satisfies the generic constraint which is indicated by a `where`) is possible, not just one.

Comment: It does not work, because "A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter."

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a Seperate TypeConverter as at Compile Time the Compiler is unaware of Type T and whether it can be converted to float .

you can use Convert.ChangeType Method to Convert

```
public class ConvertTypeClass<T1,T2>
    {
        public T1 ConvertMethod(T2 val)
        {
            return (T1) (Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T1)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem given that the basic arithmetic types do not have a common interface (e.g. INumeric) which you could use to restrict your method, via where T : INumeric.

There is, however, a slightly clumsy workaround, which does compile!  If you include your code within a typeof condition, the compiler is happy.  For example:

```
private void PerformWindowLevel<T>(int lower, int upper, ref T[] pixels) 
{
    if ((typeof(T) == typeof(byte)) || (typeof(T) == typeof(int)))
    {
        float shift = 1;
        float scale = 2;
        float val = ((float)(object)pixels[0] + shift) * scale;
    }  
}
```

All you need to do, is to include in your surrounding if condition, as many types as you need!  As I say a bit clumsy, but it works!