# return generic parameter of type and perform operation

Tags: c#

Is it possible to perform operations on a generically passed parameter in C#? 
I created this minimal example to demonstrate *a potential* usecase.

```
private T genericFormatterTest<T>(T x)
{
    if (Type.Equals(x, typeof(int)))
    {
        return (int)x * (int)x; //squared
    } else if (Type.Equals(x, typeof(string)))
    {
        return x.ToString()+"\n";
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException(); //or another suitable exception
}
...
int    squared =  genericFormatterTest<int>(5);
string newline =  genericFormatterTest<string>("hello");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)

Comment: @Tikkes Nope, thats just returning different types. Not performing operations on them.

Comment: What would you expect `genericFormatterTest<long>(10L)` to do? That's going to try to return a string as a long...

Comment: @JonSkeet This question is simply asking for a "working" concept or POC. "*Is it possible?*"

Comment: But if we don't know how you'd want it to handle particular situations, even for an example, we can't tell whether or not it's possible to perform that behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point, I'll think about it some more.  *To answer your previous question:* I would expect long to return a long, not a string ^^

Comment: @JonSkeet The example i provided is just a minimal one. You could consider the else statement to throw an explicit conversion error or something in that nature. Each possible type that would be passable would be in an `else if(...)`

Comment: @Joel: "Minimal" isn't useful if it's not clear what you expect to happen though. It still needs to be complete enough for us to help you without having to guess. If you're happy for it to throw an exception, make the example do that. Note that if this is an unconstrained generic method, then you *can't* have an `else if` for every possible type.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question, hopefully it has made it clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. The following code works and is 'generic'

```
private T genericFormatterTest<T>(T x)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        return (T)(object)((int)(object)x * (int)(object)x); //squared
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)(object)(x + "\n");
    }
}
```

But is this *really* what you want?

Used samples from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170784/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-t-to-int)

Using the same example you could also introduce a constraint on T, but it only slightly (and arguably) reduces how badly it reads:

```
private T genericFormatterTest<T>(T x) where T: IConvertible
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        return (T)(object)(Convert.ToInt32(x) * Convert.ToInt32(x)); //squared
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)(object)(x + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: _But is this really what you want?_ is quite important. I don't think you should ever do something like this in a real world scenario and honestly also not in most other scenarios.

Comment: Urgghh, Was hoping for a more elegant solution to be possible. With this approach I'd might aswell get rid of generics and use dynamic. However, you answered the question. +1